# Существует ли универсальный интерфейс для управления Flash-объектом через Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, flash-player

Всем привет. Хотелось бы узнать, существует ли возможность обратиться ( управлять ) к **любому** Flash-объекту через Javascript? То есть play, pause и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Так для этого есть класс `ExternalInterface`.